# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 while storing the result as a tuple in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, imagenet

I want to store the result in a data-frame in form of a tuple with (predictions, probabilities) in each tags. I can print fine the result at the line:
print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
I'm getting the error for the line :
    Error message:
        temprow[i+1] = (predictions[i],probabilities[i])
    IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

execution_path = os.getcwd()
pred_array = np.empty((0,6),dtype=object)

TEST_PATH = '/home/guest/Documents/Aikomi'
for img in os.listdir(TEST_PATH):
    if img.endswith('.jpg'):
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, img))
        image = image.convert("RGB")
        image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
        prediction = ImagePrediction()
        prediction.setModelTypeAsDenseNet()
        prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "DenseNet.h5"))
        prediction.loadModel()
        predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, img), result_count=5 )
        temprow = np.zeros((1,pred_array.shape[1]),dtype=object)
        temprow[0] = img
        for i in range(len(predictions)):
            temprow[i+1] = (predictions[i],probabilities[i])
        for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
            #print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
            pred_array = np.append(pred_array,temprow,axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pred_array,columns=['File_name','Tag_1','Tag_2','Tag_3','Tag_4','Tag_5'])    
print(df)
df.to_csv('Image_tags.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got a fix with the dimension mismatch.

```
pred_array = np.empty((0,6),dtype=object)
for img in os.listdir(TEST_PATH):
    if img.endswith('.jpg'):
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, img))
        image = image.convert("RGB")
        image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
        predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(TEST_PATH, img), result_count=5)
        temprow = np.zeros((1,pred_array.shape[1]),dtype=object)
        temprow[0,0] = img
        for i in range(len(predictions)):
            temprow[0,i+1] = predictions[i]
        pred_array = np.append(pred_array,temprow,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have defined:

```
pred_array = np.empty((0,6),dtype=object)
```

it should be:

```
pred_array = np.empty((1,6),dtype=object)
```

zero means no axis, but it show as (0, 6) if you get pred_array.shape, which maybe misleading a bit.

and :

```
temprow = np.zeros((1,pred_array.shape[1]),dtype=object)
```

later you are indexing:

```
 for i in range(len(predictions)):
        temprow[i+1] = (predictions[i],probabilities[i])
```

temprow only has one index room to access for it's first axis since you have defined it's shape as (1, pred_array,shape[1]). numpy arrays do not have dynamic size allocation property to index at out range and it be made for you.

Comment: How do you think I should initialise the temprow so as to match the indexing?

Comment: the number of elements you need to put in it: 

`temprow = np.zeros((len(predictions),pred_array.shape[1]),dtype=object) `